# Java - record multiple user inputs per another input

Tags: java, loops, foreach, record, prompt

This program should ask for a student name. Then, for each student, four grades will be recorded. Then iterate again until the user enters "C" to exit loop. Then print the results. 
It only shows the last four elements entered. I think my for loop isn't going to accomplish what I want. Do I need .forEach perhaps? After this, I also must sum up each four numbers per student separately. Must I have a different arrayList per student?
Here's what I have so far:

```
package arrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> studentName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
boolean loop = true;
while (loop) {
  System.out.println(" Please Enter Student Name");
  sc.nextLine();

      String student = sc.nextLine();

        if(student.equals("C"))
        {
          break;    
        }
        else
        {
          studentName.add(student);
        }


        ArrayList<Double> studentGrade = new ArrayList<Double>();
    System.out.println("Please enter Student Grade");
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        Double grade = sc.nextDouble();
        studentGrade.add(grade);  
    }    
    System.out.println(studentName);
    System.out.print(studentGrade);
    }
}
}
```

I want to print the elements of each arrayList in order of entry, first studentName then studentGrade.
Would .forEach help?

Comment: Why not create a `Student` class that will contain an array of *his/her* marks? That way you can just have a `List<Student>` and all the information you need will be contained in that collection..

Comment: I need to sum up all of the double values (grades) per student, and I'm not summing up names of students. Unless you mean that I can create an array inside the arrayList? I'm not sure how that works

Comment: Okay so then inside the `Student` class you can have a property called `sumOfMarks` instead of the array of marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters I would suggest to get the users input using the `Console` class. 
Also:

1. The first time you are calling `sc.nextLine()`, you are getting input from
   the user and never store it.
2. You should initialize your `ArrayList<Double> studentGrade` out of
   the loop. Every time you are looping for input it creates a
   new list and you are loosing the student grades of the previous
   loop.

Run this, if you have to change to `Scanner` again, use `Scanner`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Console;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> studentName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<Double> studentGrade = new ArrayList<Double>();
boolean loop = true;

while (loop) {

    System.out.println(" Please Enter Student Name");
    String student = scanner.nextLine();

        if(student.equals("C"))
        {
          break;    
        }
        else
        {
          studentName.add(student);
        }


    System.out.println("Please enter Student Grade");
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        Double grade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        studentGrade.add(grade);  
    }    

    System.out.println(studentName);
    System.out.print(studentGrade);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Themelis- this looks great, and I understand the feedback. It said class Test must be defined in its own file, so I changed it back to TestGrades. I also deleted the " ``` " at the very end of the code because it caused an error. But now when I run it, it immediately crashes: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The name of the file and the class must be the same. Rename your file to `Test.java` for example and also name the class `Test` (or any names you like).

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue. I changed Test back to TestGrades. I mentioned the issues I'm facing now.

Comment: For me it's working. I've made an edit on the code also and removed the "```". Create a Test.java file, paste the code from above and execute it. Question are you using a console to run the code or an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: That may be the issue. I'm running Eclipse

Comment: Ok my bad, you can switch back to `Scanner`, but keep in mind that this has to be closed when its done. I am editing the code...

Comment: Don't forget to change the name of the class to the name of the file its been written.

Comment: Thank you Themelis. This is an improvement over my code, for sure. But still, since I must sum up each set of four grades separately, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Steve if its an improvement you should upvote the answer.

Comment: Yes, my votes don't affect the publically viewed score but I did. Just need to figure out how to sum up each student's grades

Comment: The grades are stored in `studentGrade`. Whatever operation you want to do next you can manipulate them from the list.

Comment: My issue is that me manually getting the elements and adding them up isn't going to cut it. The user can input any number of students and therefore any number of grades. I need each set of 4 grades per student to be added up separately. I believe that means each set of 4 grades will have to be separate from each other, i.e. not on the same list if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Well in that case you could take advantage of Object Oriented Programing, create a class `Student` which holds 4 grades (you can have a double array `double[]`) and in the `main()` you will need to have only one `ArrayList`. The ArrayList<Student>.